# How do I add a class to the search block form?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to add a class to the `<form>` element on the form_id 'search_block_form'

this is my current code

```
function THEME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-inline ';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `template_preprocess_form`

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_form(&$vars) {
  // Add class to your specific form
  if ($vars['attributes']['id'] == 'search-block-form') {
    $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'form-inline ';
  }
}
```

NOTE: the preprocessor you are using adds class to the block element

Comment: I am confused about:

`function THEMENAME_preprocess_form(&$vars)`
and
`function THEMENAME_preprocess_form(&$variables)`

What is the difference?

Comment: What is confusing ? ... please be more specific.

Comment: `$vars` VS `$variables`

Comment: Its a local variable to your function so you can name it anything you want ... but have to use the same name throughout your function

Answer (score -1):

Try this code..

```
/*
* Implement hook_form_alter()
*/
function custom_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test';
}
```

Comment: `hook_form_alter` adds the classes to the block/wrapper element, not the form tag. `hook_preprocess_form` is what allows you to add attributes directly to the form tag.